# Jquery remove text from span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery and really struggling how to perform the query I want.

I'm using SharePoint, and the when using the External Data Column and set it to required field, the error message always appears until you fill in the data. Unlike other type columns where they only appear after you click OK/Save and not filled in the data. Therefore I need to remove the error message text just from these type of columns.

I assume I need to search for span within the .ms-error class that contains the words 'External Data' and hide it.

From using IE developer toolbar, I've identified the area.

```
 <table class="ms-usereditor" id="ctl00_m_g_05df537a_596b_443a_a11e_764069facec8_ctl00_Field_External_539c53fe_8334_43c8_b089_cc28d7895e68_Picker_OuterTable" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td colSpan="3">
       <span class="ms-error" id="ctl00_m_g_05df537a_596b_443a_a11e_764069facec8_ctl00_Field_External_539c53fe_8334_43c8_b089_cc28d7895e68_Picker_errorLabel">
           Text - You must specify a value before using the Check button. You can also use Select button to choose External Data.
        </span>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please can someone help me with the JQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('span.ms-error:contains("External Data")').hide();`

If you know for sure that these `span`'s are inside a certain `table` or a `div` then target it specifically inside those to make the script perform better.

eg.

`$('.ms-usereditor span.ms-error:contains("External Data")').hide();`

Comment: i may be wrong, but unless you know the ID of their container this won't perform any faster than with just the `ms-error` class selector

Comment: Thank you Moin. I swear what you put is what I tried. I did a copy and paste directly from here to my code, and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Paul: You're welcome! It couldn't have been the same I think. Maybe the double quote inside `contains`?

Answer (score 47):

```
var spans = $('.ms-error');

spans.text(''); // clear the text
spans.hide(); // make them display: none
spans.remove(); // remove them from the DOM completely
spans.empty(); // remove all their content
```

Comment: `.empty()` and `.text('')` do the same thing

Comment: Thank you but this also removes the error messages from other fields that aren't External data. Such as people picker.

Comment: i used `.text(' ')`.  Works great because it clears it from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Here's more optimised and faster approach:

```
$(".ms-usereditor span[class^='ms-error']:contains('External Data')").hide()
```

And additionally, this syntax works as a charm when you require a sort of regex pattern to find all matching nodes or nodes with similar classnames. Suppose, you need to find something *.ms-error-1* *.ms-error-abc*. So, same syntax works and even better you could do like this:

```
$(".ms-usereditor span[class^='ms-error-']:contains('External Data')").hide()
```