# How to clear the span text which is indiv

Tags: html, jquery

I have two divs and i have multiple spans as shown below.How can i clear this span text

```
<div1>
<div2>
<Span></span>
<span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default k-state-hover">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-input">should clear</span>  //how to clear this text
</div2>
</div1>
```

I also tried

```
document.getElementById("#divid span").innerHTML="";
```

[still not getting cleared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf5Aq.png)

Comment: so select the element and empty it?

Comment: i tried span.html="": but its no working

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/empty

Comment: i tried but its not working

Comment: well that is not valid jquery. `$(".k-input").empty()`

Comment: well you can not use selectors in `getElementById`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery remove text from span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207432/jquery-remove-text-from-span)

Comment: $("#divActivitySection").text('');
using this complete div gets hidden

Comment: `<div1>` is **invalid** HTML. There is no `<div1>` tag. Same with `<div2>`. `unselectable` is an invalid attribute on `span`. Again, invalid HTML.

Comment: `document.getElementById("#divid span")` is an invalid argument. `id` cannot contain whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

`<div1>` is **invalid** HTML. There is no `<div1>` tag. Same with `<div2>`. `unselectable` is an invalid attribute on `span`. Again, invalid HTML.

`"#divid span"` is an invalid argument for `document.getElementById()`. `id` cannot contain whitespace.

With your HTML corrected to be actually valid (which is a **must** in any web development), here you go:

```js
document.querySelector('.k-input').textContent = '';
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <span></span>
    <span data-unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default k-state-hover">
      <span data-unselectable="on" class="k-input">should clear</span> //how to clear this text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And from the first Answer you can try giving your second div class like:

```
<div>
  <div class="second-div">
    <span></span>
    <span data-unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default k-state-hover">
      <span data-unselectable="on" class="k-input">should clear</span> //how to clear this text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And your javascript like:

```
  div = document.querySelector('.second-div');

  for (var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++) {      
      div.childNodes[i].innerHTML = '';
  }
```

This loop through the second div and clear it children

But if you have other elements in the second div and wanted to clear only the spans you can also try this:

```
let div = document.querySelector('.second-div');
let spans = div.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
   spans[i].innerHTML = '';
}
```